# clicking on the name of the person who last posted in a thread should take us to his post not his profile

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

For example I see that the last person who posted on a particular question was Jon Skeet then obviously i'd be interested in his reply rather than seeing his profile.

I think its makes more sense that navigation links on the questions list should take us to questions not user profiles.

Comment: I do this every damn time.

Comment: no it shouldn't. clicking a username should always, consistently, take you to the profile. What you want is a link to take you to the post. This is an additional link. Not an re-direction of the existing link.

Comment: @cometbill - Agreed! Am I the only one annoyed by the fact that clicking on the username of a CW brings me to their revision and not their profile?

Comment: @comet, you should post that as an answer, since this is a feature request.

Comment: If it was a female poster, you've performed a sex change with a single click. Major bug!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it shouldn't.

Currently, a `Question` listing has a **four**-fold navigation functionality.

[image]

Your proposal would reduce navigation functionality by **25%**.

It sounds like you should be clicking on `TIME ago`.

---

Do note that the 4th functionality only applies to the "micro views" and not the "mini views". I am not sure why this is.

Comment: Timestamp is an extra function click.

Comment: @random - Fancy that. Hadn't noticed until you pointed it out.... sounds like that's excactly the functionality OP is looking for.

Answer (score 4):

There is existing functionality to perform this navigation. It is one more click if you're navigating from the questions list, but I think it's a lot more functional to rely on that than to introduce a break in consistency for the username links on the site. I actually find utility in navigating to the profile from the front page and the questions list, but that may just be me.

When looking at a question that has had activity, the right sidebar includes a field called "last activity". Its value, which for new activity will generally be "today", is actually a link. Clicking on it will skip through the question and direct you straight to the most recent activity that you are seeking.

If you're on the front page, this is even faster. Clicking on the timestamp next to the username will navigate to the same URL as the last activity, so you'll basically be brought to the post from that user. This functionality is not present on the questions list, but that sounds like a proper feature request on its own.

Comment: +1.  Username links are links to user profiles - changing it so some link to latest activity and others link to profiles is just terrible for consistency.

Comment: For anyone who wants to whip up some sort of custom UI implementation (GreaseMonkey, or whateverelse whathaveyou) of the mentioned proper feature request, the URL for the last activity is simply the URL of the question with `?lastactivity` at the end. Like: `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63880/clicking-on-the-name-of-the-person-who-last-posted-in-a-thread-should-take-us-to/?lastactivity`

Answer (score 3):

> clicking on the name of the person who
>   last posted in a thread should take us
>   to his post not his profile

No, it shouldn't. clicking a username should always, consistently, take you to the profile. What you want is a link to take you to the post. This is an additional link. Not an re-direction of the existing (profile) link.

Answer (score 2):

This is already possible, as Peter points out -- just click on the time.

(note that it only applies to the "micro" question view seen on the homepage and profiles, not the "mini" question view seen on question brows lists.)

Comment: Why doesn't the "mini" view have the same `"TIME ago"` navigation functionality as the "micro" view?

Comment: The fact that you guys had to tell me that the 'time ago' label is a link, means there is something wrong with the Usability. From the face of it that doesn't look like a link.

Answer (score -1):

Hasan - just to clarify, is feature reqeust only for the Active Tab.
As per the screen shots below?

For Questions displayed on the `active` tab

[image]

When clicking on the name it should take you here:
[image]

Not take you here asit does currently
[image]

Comment: Yes thats what I mean. There is no point in having 2 links in that small area which are barely noticeable. The whole modified box should just take you to that post.