# Clicking on "TIME ago"should have the same functionality in "micro" and "mini" view

Tags: feature-request, navigation

**[Jeff pointed this out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63880/clicking-on-the-name-of-the-person-who-last-posted-in-a-thread-should-take-us-to/63942#63942)** in  **[this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63880/clicking-on-the-name-of-the-person-who-last-posted-in-a-thread-should-take-us-to)**.

Currently, in most situations (*a question's "micro view"*) a question listing has four fold navigation functionality:

---

[image]

---

However, if you click on `Questions` in the upper left, you get taken to a page with a slightly different formatting (*the "mini view"*) and limited navigation functionality:

---

[image]

---

It'd be more consistent and more useful to have the `TIME ago`, last changed item, navigation functionality for both the "micro" and "mini" views.

Also, it'd be nice to have the votes and views be consistently clickable or not (I don't think it matters which way) between the "micro" and "mini" views..

Comment: Freehand circles: check.  Freehand writing: check.  Upvote!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite possible; look closely at the dates for each tab.

They change.

On some tabs, it's showing "when was this question *created/asked*" -- on others it is indeed showing the last change.

(in particular on the view/tab you've provided, it would be wrong, though it would be correct on some others)

Comment: The timestamp, if it becomes a link, should link to the post.  Because that is what the time stamp represents, the time the question was asked.

Comment: p.s. [Enter] to submit a comment rocks, thanks

Comment: Interesting differences. I've never really used the "mini" views, since I've always clicked on the `"Stack Overflow"` logo (for the "micro" views) instead of the `"Questions"` box (for the "mini" views).